# Printf to the terminal blocking user input in C?

Tags: c

Mock up of the structure of the code:

```
// Thread void printToScreen(){
    while(1){
        printf("Hello");
        while(state == 1){
            //Wait
        }
    }
}

main(){
    while(1){
        scanf("%s",str);
        if(String == END){
            // End printToScreen();
            state = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

When it is constantly printing to the terminal, it ignores my scanf inputs. If there is a break in the printing to the terminal (Lets say waiting for 1 second), I can then type my input in. I want to type the input in at any time even when it is currently printing to the terminal. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `scanf();` should invoke *undefined behavior* for luck of arguments.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use **gets( )** from *string.h* llibrary:

If you press **ENTER** key it takes it as `\0`

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>


    void printToScreen(){
        char str[100];
        int i;
        while(1){

            for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                scanf("%c",&str[i]);
                if(str[i]=='\n') break;
            }
            if(!strcmp("END\n",str)) return ;
        printf("Hello\n");  
        }
    }

    int main(){
         printToScreen();
         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `gets` is deprecated because of its buffer overflow vulnerability. Please don't recommend it. Also, you should google 'How to compare two strings in C".

Comment: ooh  thx.. i always forget `strcmp`

Comment: Looks like you also forget how `strcmp()` works.

Comment: how can you do if we have **string**?? instard of `gets` @CoolGuy

Comment: Is this  edited program stable  @CoolGuy